# Select from openrowset bulk (path to .sql file)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, openrowset

I am trying to select from a sql file (which is a query itselft) if I paste the query as text instead of openrowset it works, but i just cant figure out the syntax below, to keep the file independent and reusable

```
select * from
    openrowset(bulk 'F:\Movimenti.sql',
        formatfile='F:\Movimenti.sql'
    ) as Test
```

due to error:
**Msg 9422, Level 16, State 48, Line 3**
**XML parsing: line 1, character 0, incorrect document syntax**

**UPDATE**

I have found another way to achieve this

```
declare @SequelFile varchar(max)
declare @sql varchar(max)

select @SequelFile=BulkColumn
from openrowset(bulk 'F:\Movimenti.sql',single_blob) x

set @sql = '
    select * from
    openquery([Navision],
    ''' + @SequelFile + '''
    ) as Derivedtbl
'
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: This seems like a solution looking for a problem. Are you trying to load sql from an external file and run it? This might be easier in CMD mode

Comment: What are trying to achieve? An excerpt from the file might be useful to understand, but the goal is more important here. Also check [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: See here for an easier way to run SQL files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840831/how-can-i-execute-a-set-of-sql-files-from-within-ssms

Comment: I used to do it using VIEW, but the ssms view editor is difficult to read and edit

the goal is to do **nested queries** , but i want to keep them divided because i need both levels, one level is grouped , the other one is not and so on.. 

so instead of having two queries with the same base, i want one query to build on top of other 

any other way to do this i welcomed... the purpose is BI and not a system, so I need to be able to change, add columns freely without having to change more than 1 query