# Run .txt file within ssms SQLCMD

Tags: ssms, sqlcmd

I want to a .txt file that contains a sql script via ssms SQLCMD query window.

Could someone give me an example.

I can run via pc CMD successfully using the following.

sqlcmd.exe -S pcName -E -i "C:\Users\user\Documents\SqlCmdTest.txt"

But how to do the same in SSMS SQLCMD please??

OR a .sql file ??

Regards

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Found Answer in the following post

[How can I execute a set of .SQL files from within SSMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840831/how-can-i-execute-a-set-of-sql-files-from-within-ssms)

within SSMS SQLCMD mode

:setvar path "c:\Path_to_scripts"
:r $(path)\file1.sql
:r $(path)\file2.sql